# When I make a updateContext Orion shuts down

Tags: xml, json, mongodb, fiware-orion

The error described here ocurred with the last version of Orion Context Broker and Mongo Server.

Query POST

```
http://127.0.0.1:1026/v1/updateContext
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
"contextElements": [
    {
        "type": "Room",
        "isPattern": "false",
        "id": "Room2",
        "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "temperature",
            "type": "float",
            "value": "15.90"
        },
        {
            "name": "pressure",
            "type": "integer",
            "value": "1021"
        }
        ]
    }
],
"updateAction": "APPEND"
```

}

ORION log:

```
INFO@16:44:47  rest.cpp[768]: Starting transaction from
127.0.0.1:43181/v1   /updateContext INFO@16:44:47 
MongoCommonUpdate.cpp[1657]: Database Operation Successful ({ 
_id.id: "Room4", _id.type: "Room", _id.servicePath: /^\/$|^\/\/.*/ 
}) 

INFO@16:44:47  MongoCommonUpdate.cpp[1454]: Database Operation 
Successful (insert { _id: { id: "Room4", type: "Room", servicePath:
"/" }, attrs: [ { name: "temperature", type: "float", creDate:
1430844287, modDate: 1430844287, value: "21" }, { name: "pressure",
type: "integer", creDate: 1430844287, modDate: 1430844287, value:
"711" } ], creDate: 1430844287, modDate: 1430844287 }) Tue May  5
18:44:47 DBClientCursor::init call() failed

ERROR@16:44:47 MongoCommonUpdate.cpp[930]: Database Error (collection:
orion.csubs - query(): { $or: [ { entities.id: "Room4", $or: [ { 
entities.type: "Room" }, { entities.type: { $exists: false } } ], 
entities.isPattern: "false", conditions.type: "ONCHANGE", 
conditions.value: "temperature", expiration: { $gt: 1430844287 }, 
servicePath: { $in: [ /^$|^/#$|^/$/, null ] } }, { entities.isPattern:
"true", conditions.type: "ONCHANGE", conditions.value: "temperature", 
expiration: { $gt: 1430844287 }, servicePath: { $in: [ /^$|^/#$|^/$/,
null ] }, $where: function(){for (var i=0; i < this.entities.length; i++) 
{if (this.enti... } ] } - exception: Null cursor from mongo (details on 
this is found in the source code)) 

INFO@16:44:47  rest.cpp[382]: Transaction ended
```

If I make the request with RestClient

Response:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Content-Length: 856
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Tue, 05 May 2015 16:44:47 GMT
```

Response body:

```
<updateContextResponse>
<contextResponseList>
<contextElementResponse>
  <contextElement>
    <entityId type="Room" isPattern="false">
      <id>Room4</id>
    </entityId>
    <contextAttributeList>
      <contextAttribute>
        <name>temperature</name>
        <type>float</type>
        <contextValue></contextValue>
      </contextAttribute>
      <contextAttribute>
        <name>pressure</name>
        <type>integer</type>
        <contextValue></contextValue>
      </contextAttribute>
    </contextAttributeList>
  </contextElement>
  <statusCode>
    <code>500</code>
    <reasonPhrase>Internal Server Error</reasonPhrase>
    <details>\&quot;</details>
  </statusCode>
</contextElementResponse>
</contextResponseList>
</updateContextResponse>
```

Sometimes it generates the entity within the database but always goes mongo

Comment: Check what version of MongoDB you are using. Orion supports MongoDB 2.4.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the following information, please? 1) contextBroker version (typically, using `contextBroker --version`), 2) MongoDB version, 3) Have you updated ContextBroker recently? 4) If 3 was yes, which one was the old version? Thanks!

Comment: In addition, I would need to understand the case a little bit more... Thus, you do the updateContext shown in the question post using RESTClient, getting the XML response also in the question post and these log messages. Is that correct? In which moment Orion shut downs? After sending the response?

Comment: Which version did you run before updating to 0.20.0, please? Did you drop the database during the update or you started to use the new Orion version without touching the database?

Comment: So, to understand it clearly, you mean that you install 0.20.0 from scractch, *without* upgrading from a previous CB version (such as 0.19.0, 0.18.0, etc.)?

Comment: In addition, reading *"I go back to the terminal where is running MongoDB this are shut downs"* I understand that the process that shut downs in the mongod server, not contextBroker itself. Is that correct?